# Matlab vpasolve numerical solver variable range

Tags: matlab, robotics

I'm trying to solve inverse kinematics for a 6DOF arm. Currently I have 6 unknowns which are the joint angles. Currently I was able to get angle values given x,y,z. However I also need constrains on the joint angles. For example:

`S=vpasolve([z(1,4)==xpos, z(2,4)==ypos, z(3,4)== zpos]);`

The answer gives 5 angles (last angle is just rotates the gripper so no positional change), the answer for first angle is:

S.ang1

`ans = -175.52966218785562632206246532588`

but as soon as I want to introduce a range for the variable:

`S=vpasolve([z(1,4)==208, z(2,4)==24 , z(3,4)== 0 ,z(3,1)==-1] , ang1, [-180 0])`

I get this error:

`MuPAD error: Error: The number of equations exceeds the number of indeterminates. This is allowed only for polynomial
systems. [numeric::solve]`

I'm not really an expert on MATLAB so I might be missing something very simple , thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that it'd be hard to help you without seeing the code behind `z(1,4)`, `z(2,4)`, `z(3,1)`, `z(3,1)`, `ang1`, and any other symbolic variables/functions that are relevant. However, the error message is pretty clear: you have four equations and only specified indeterminate. When you don't specify any variables to solve for `symvar` is used to find them – this is right in the documentation.

Comment: 'z' goes like this :  `A1=[cosd(ang1) -sind(ang1)*cosd(alfa1) sind(ang1)*sind(alfa1) r1*cosd(ang1); sind(ang1) cosd(ang1)*cosd(alfa1) -cosd(ang1)*sind(alfa1) r1*sind(ang1) ; 0 sind(alfa1) cosd(alfa1) d1; 0 0 0 1];`

and A2 is just with different angle names , I have 6 angles which are variable and then which calculates the matrices A2 A3 A4 A5 A6, and then 

`z=A1*A2*A3*A4*A5*A6`

Comment: @horchler the problem is that i can't specify the range of the variables , its not in the documentation of vpasolve, they only give example for a single variable and it gives error when I give range to each variable.

Comment: The code still is not runnable (you should always edit your question rather than pasting code into a comment too). As I stated above, you have four equations and you only specified indeterminate. Have you tried solving for four angles (you could provide ranges for some or all maybe)? That or substitute in numeric values to reduce the number of equations (using `subs`). The number of equations and unknown must be equal.

Comment: And [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpasolve.html#bt5sqi5-1_1) seems clear to me. A matrix with two columns and the same number of rows as unknowns – click on "init_guess" in the doc to read further details. Use `[NaN NaN]` for a row if you don't want specify a range for a particular variable